How to change the subtotal or grand total formula in Pivot Table
i have created an excel sheet and assign a pivot table to it , in the pivot table it shows total sum of invoicing & retailing. below is the eg.
This is what my Pivot dashboard shows
Product Name| invoicing | retailing |Total Sum
Product 1   | 12000     | 10000     |22000
Product 2   | 15000     | 16000     |31000
Product 3   | 10000     | 10000     |20000

What i actually want is the (Invoicing - Retailing ) value in total sum.eg (12000-10000 = 2000)
Please Help.
I tried doing it manually on the dashboard itself , i know i am doing it in a wrong way. enter image description here
this is what i did to all the rows manually , but when i change the month it gives error for other rows.

In your source data, can you enter the retailing as negative numbers? Failing that, you could probably add a calculated field to accomplish that.

Why not just do the calculation B2-C2 ?

You would need to use Calculated Field --> =' invoicing ' -' retailing '

Try using Calculated Field in Pivot Tables:


Name: Difference --> Formula: --> =' invoicing ' -' retailing '

